# How to change class on click using Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

```
<div><img class="login-normal"alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAC8AAAA8AQMAAADMq3HaAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAA5JREFUeNpjYBgFgx0AAAGkAAF+IKsZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"><a class="login"></a></div>
```

I want to change the class from login-normal to login-sel,
I have a images on both of the class.

By on click the class wants to change it was to be in pure angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In future, please redact the base64 image, as it throws the code formatting off. :)

There are many different ways to do this. The simplest would be to have a click handler change the class in your typescript.

*In your component*

```
imageClass: string = 'login-normal'

toggleLoginClass(event: MouseEvent | any) {
   event.preventDefault();
   this.imageClass = this.imageClass === 'login-normal' ? 'login-sel' : 'login-normal';
}
```

*In your template*

```
<div><img (click)="toggleLoginClass($event)" [class]="imageClass" alt="" src="data:image"><a class="login"></a></div>
```